# How to create a UISearchBar in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-environment

I am trying to create my own SwiftUI version of a `UISearchBar`, for learning purposes.

I have followed [this tutorial](https://mobileinvader.com/search-bar-in-swiftui/)

and at this point my search bar struct is like this:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
    
struct SearchBarUI: View {
  
  @Binding var searchText:String
  var textColor:Color
  var boxColor:Color
  var boxHeight:CGFloat
      
  public init(_ text:Binding<String>, textColor:Color, boxColor:Color, boxHeight:CGFloat) {
    self._searchText = text
    self.textColor = textColor
    self.boxColor = boxColor
    self.boxHeight = boxHeight
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
        .padding(.leading, -10)
        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
      TextField("Search", text: $searchText, onCommit:  {
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first { $0.isKeyWindow }?.endEditing(true)
      })
      .padding(.leading, 10)
      Button(action: {
        self.searchText = ""
      }) {
        Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
          .foregroundColor(.secondary)
          .opacity(searchText == "" ? 0 : 1)
          .animation(.linear)
      }
    }.padding(.horizontal)
  }
}
```

But here is the problem.

When I use this searchbar at ContentView, I want the search text variable to be like this:

```
class GlobalVariables: ObservableObject {
  @Published var searchText:String = ""
}

@EnvironmentObject var globalVariables : GlobalVariables

SearchBarUI(globalVariables.searchText,
            textColor:.black,
            boxColor:.gray,
            boxHeight:50)
```

because the value of the search text must propagate to other interface elements, that will react to the change.

But then I have this error on the `SearchBarUI` line, pointing to `globalVariables.searchText`:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'
```

How do I solve that?

Comment: You need binding, but at first what is `globalVariables` and what is `throttleModel` in it?

Comment: sorry, typo. I have fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how to pass binding for observed object published property

```
@EnvironmentObject var globalVariables : GlobalVariables

// ... other code

SearchBarUI($globalVariables.searchText,     // << here !!
```

Comment: For heaven's sake. obviously! I am new to SwiftUI and my brain is failing to wrap around it. Thanks